# Git: Stage Change vs Git: Stage Changes

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, version-control

What's the difference between these two commands: `Git: Stage Change` and `Git: Stage Changes` in VSCode? `Git: Stage Change` seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `git.stageChange` command only appears (it is explicitly configured not to show up in the command palette) in the in-line diff editor, which can be accessible by clicking on the SCM editor decoration (added/edited/deleted lines) available in the left-hand gutter of the editor:

[image: demo]

The `Git: Stage Changes` and `Git: Stage All Changes` are the commands to stage changes for one/all file(s).